# How do I close a button in HTML when another button is clicked on so the collapse's text does not overlap/button's data

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4

As you see in the code when you open the first button and the second button their data overlaps. I want it to not overlap, so when the first button's data is open and a user clicks on the second button, the first button's data close, so it is not as confusing to read.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Website</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Primary, secondary, success, info, warning, danger, dark, light, link -->
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="row">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" id="button0">Simple collapsible</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" id="button1">Simple collapsible</button>
          <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea                 commodo consequat.
          </div>
          <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea                 commodo consequat.
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf3ZE.png)

Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the below code as I mentioned, it working with data-parent and id parent of the div

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Website</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Primary, secondary, success, info, warning, danger, dark, light, link -->
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
    <div class="row" id="accordionExample">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" id="button0">Simple collapsible</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" id="button1">Simple collapsible</button>
              <div id="demo2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea                 commodo consequat.
              </div>
              <div id="demo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea                 commodo consequat.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much just started learning bootstrap.